# Click on checkbox next to dropdown item selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to click on the check box for a relevant date from a dropdown list

[image]

So I need to find the correct date via the text of the span element
Below I have added partial code and a screenshot of everything as I am not sure how much of the code you might need.
If more code is required I will happily update the post.

```
<div class="row" role="none">
<div class="slicerItemContainer" tabindex="0" role="option" aria-checked="false" aria-setsize="-1" aria-posinset="1" data-row-index="1" data-row-id="0:1" style="margin-left: 0px;" pbi-focus-tracker-idx="6">
<div class="slicerCheckbox" aria-hidden="true">
<span class="glyphicon checkbox checkboxOutline" style="font-size: 13.3333px;">
</span>
</div>
<span class="slicerText" title="Wednesday, February 01, 2023" style="color: rgb(0, 51, 161); border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(0, 51, 161); border-width: 0px; font-size: 13.3333px; font-family: &quot;Segoe UI&quot;; line-height: 17px; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none;">Wednesday, February 01, 2023</span>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

The variable containing my formatted date is `prev_date` and the code I tried using is this

```
    Date_xpath= '//span[text()="'+prev_date+'"]/preceding-sibling::div[@class = "slicerCheckbox"]'
    Submit = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,Date_xpath )))
    Submit.click()
```

But I am just getting a timeout error.

Some guidance would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). You may like to consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Like @undetected Selenium said update your question. What i would try though by looking at the HTML, is this xpath `//span[text()="'+prev_date+'"]/parent::div`

Comment: @RolandasUlevicius no luck with this solution. 
It just times out

Answer (score 1):

`xpath` looks fine, However it seems element is not visible on the page, Try with `presence_of_element_located()` instead of `element_to_be_clickable()`

```
Date_xpath= '//span[text()="'+prev_date+'"]/preceding-sibling::div[@class = "slicerCheckbox"]'
Submit = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,Date_xpath )))
Submit.click()
```

If you get any error other than `timeout` then use `javascripts` executor to click

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", Submit)
```

If you still get `timeout` error then please check element is inside an `iframe` or not.

Comment: This might be a silly question but how do I check if the element is in an iframe or not?

Comment: Also I am not sure if it is worth noting but the date I am trying to select is at the bottom of the dropdown list. So you would need to scroll down to find it

Comment: @Susan-l3p, Are you still getting `timeout` error? the element you are searching traverse upwards and check if parent node have tag <iframe>, If the element not inside  iframe and present in DOM, then prersense_of_element() should find the element atleast

Comment: Yes I still get a timeout error. I have checked and can't find any iframe tags. Another thing that I have noticed now. It is able to select dates that are at the top of the list. It just can't find the dates that you would need to scroll down to.

Comment: Ok that means element is not present in the DOM initially, you need to scroll and then element will be available in DOM. If possible share your url.

Comment: How do I scroll? Unfortunately can't share the URL since it's a company powerbi report